# Unable to work with android-gif-drawable library

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
07-10 01:06:36.136: E/AndroidRuntime(2658): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView" on path: /data/app/com.littlejavachild.mozmeet-1.apk
07-10 01:06:36.136: E/AndroidRuntime(2658):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
07-10 01:06:36.136: E/AndroidRuntime(2658):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-10 01:06:36.136: E/AndroidRuntime(2658):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-10 01:06:36.136: E/AndroidRuntime(2658):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:565)
07-10 01:06:36.136: E/AndroidRuntime(2658):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
07-10 01:06:36.136: E/AndroidRuntime(2658):     ... 24 more
```

I am trying to use [android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable/releases/tag/v1.0.8) for my Android project. I downloaded the `sources.jar` file and added it to my Eclipse's libs folder. However, I still get the exception. How can I add that to my project, correctly?

*PS: I tried extracting it and importing an existing Android project into workspace but that did not work either. I even tried copy-pasting it into my workspace and working with it. I got an `UnsatisfiedLinkException`*

Answer (score 0):

You have no native libraries (.so files). If you are using Eclipse you must either compile native sources or copy compiled files. See [this issue on github](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable/issues/78)